# Class Based View alternative for deprecated redirect_to in Django 1.3 onwards

Tags: python, django, django-views

When I attempt to use `django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to` I get a deprecation notice. It seems that `redirect_to` has been deprecated from Django 1.3 onwards (See the first note in documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/).

Previously I could do this (in this example I redirect the signup page of userena to home):

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

url(r'^accounts/signup/$',
    redirect_to, {'url':'/', 'permanent':False},
    name='userena_signup'),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use `django.views.generic.RedirectView` class based view as an alternative.

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

url(r'^accounts/signup/$',
    RedirectView.as_view(url='/', permanent=False),
    name='userena_signup'),
```

Most of the generic method based views can be replaced with [generic class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#generic-views).